# How to concatenate string and javascript variable inside jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I concatenate a string with a javascript variable inside a jquery selector?
If I execute the code below. All the other form elements gets hidden.

```
var inputatr = $('input[type=text]').attr(); //button
$('input[value=string ' +  inputatr +']').hide(); //textbox
```

**Update**

```
<?php for($x=0; $x<4; $x++){ ?>

<input type="text" id="<?php echo $x; ?>" name="<?php echo $x; ?>" value="text<?php echo $x; ?>"/>
<input type="button" name="show<?php echo $x; ?>" value="string<?php echo $x; ?>"/></li>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What do you want the result to be? I don't what you get when you don't pass a parameter to `attr`. Check what `inputatr` contains. String concatenation works this way, but make sure you produce the right string. Please post your HTML.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I have updated my question, please see it,thanks

Comment: @user225269 I think what you're trying to accomplish is actually contrary what you have actually posted.  If my presumption is correct, you're trying to make the textbox hide when the user clicks the corresponding button.  is that correct?

Comment: Provide us an exemple of the desired result please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to locate all your textboxes and hide the one with the value of `'string'`?  If so, the way to do that is actually something more like this:

```
$('input[type=text]').filter('input[value=string]').hide()
```

Updated because of your update:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(event)
{
    var strNum = $(this).val('name').replace('string', '');

    $('#' + strNum).hide();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`$('input[value="string' +  inputatr +'"]').hide();`

This hides the input with the value equal to `inputatr`

Comment: I have a string value before the the value attribute of the textbox:
<input type="text" value="string<?php $id; ?>"/>

Comment: his text input values are text+number, and all his buttons are named string+number - this wont select any textbox when he clicks the button.